# Aria-owns without using an id

Tags: javascript, html, dom, accessibility

Html ids are kind of the antithesis of good web application development. When you use reusable components, having IDs anywhere immediately either makes your component non-reusable, or forces you to manage a unique set of ids, which is bad for code maintenance and can easily introduce errors.

Aria-owns seems to *require* the use of ids. I would have assumed there would be a way to specify an a11y relationship in javascript with bare dom node references, but I can't seem to find anything like that.

Is there any way of avoiding ids if you want to use accessibility features like aria-owns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shadow DOM is a good way to include web components while avoiding `id` attributes overlapping.

The DOM shadow boundary would prevent any problem while still enabling screenreaders to parse the accessibility tree

Answer (score 0):

No. HTML attributes can't use JS references.

IDs are the standard means to identify an element.

Generate a unique ID for the elements you need to reference: You already have a DOM reference in your JS to set it on.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you understand the problems with using IDs in a web application. Standard or not, they should be avoided. There are other ways of identifying elements that are more conducive to application development. Generating a random id is a good workaround idea tho, thanks!

Comment: I understand the limitations perfectly well. That doesn’t change how HTML and browsers work.

Comment: In React, there is the useId() hook that can be used for this purpose: https://react.dev/reference/react/useId